# I can't tab through player controls in Internet Explorer using mediaelement.js

Tags: internet-explorer, keyboard, accessibility, mediaelement.js, tabindex

I'm using ME on pages that are being tested for keyboard accessibility across browsers. It works as expected in Chrome, and Firefox: I can use the tab key to move through all links on the page and all the ME player controls. Shift+tab moves me backward through all controls and links. Perfect.

In IE 10 and 11 on Windows 7 I get this result: I can tab through links and into the player, but when I press tab again focus jumps into the browser address bar and then gets trapped. Every time I press tab it just cycles through the browser menu, and I can't get back into the page or player.

Just to make sure I hadn't broken my player, I tested the ME example on this page: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=loop and got the same result.

Any idea how to fix that IE problem? Thank you!

Comment: Just a confirmation that I see the same problem.  I have W7 and it works in firefox but not IE 11.  So hopefully that helps.  It's not just the way your system is configured.  I would suggest contacting their support.  It looks like Safari has the same problem - https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1873

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Unlike the post on Git, I agree with you that I'm having no trouble in FF. Only IE11